# Multiple files upload in grails

Tags: ajax, grails, file-upload

I am trying to implement a comment mechanism in which a user can post a comment and also upload multiple files with it. I am using a g:formRemote for the comment part but I learned that ajax request does not supports file uploads. SO how do I do this? I found few plugins but they did not work for me as I have to save comments as well and these plugins did not support that. I found a way on internet by using iframes, but I am not sure how to do that. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What plugin do you prefer to use? It's possible with any plugin, but each plugin have own specifics

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery Form plugin, it supports [ajax file uploads as well](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) so you don't need to implement this by yourself. It also allows to track upload progress.